# Bevel edges create new verticles

Tags: modeling, bevel

hellowhen I use Bevel Edges (Ctrl + B in edit mode) I get vertices. And as I understand, 2 vertices are created in one place, i need to remove the vertices 2 times so that it disappears. Why is this and how can this be avoided?
Here are examples in the screenshots
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks as if you may have extra overlapping vertices before you run the bevel. Try selecting All in Edit mode and then press 'M' > By Distance to merge any duplicates and then try bevelling again.

Comment: I tried to manually remove them, but it turned out that there is no overlapping vertices. But your method helped, thanks a lot!